How to find the point where a ridge 'statistically' dissipates?
Here is an image of a surface $\mathcal{M}$ of my interest.

The surface is estimated from a family of curves $z=f_x(y)$ (each curve is a measured physical profile of some object) assigned with $x$ variables. I performed bivariate Nadaraya-Watson kernel regression on point cloud $(x, y, f_x(y))$ to acquire smooth $\mathcal{M}$. Below is an image of $z=f_x(y)$ curves.

Let $m_x(y)$ be an intersection curve between $\mathcal{M}$ and a $yz$-parallel plane with $x$ coordinate. $m_x(y)$ shows a prominent peak (local maximum) on small $x$, but the peak gradually dissipates as $x$ increases. Below is an image of two curves $m_{x_\mathrm{min}}(y)$ and $m_{x_\mathrm{max}}(y)$:

Back to $\mathcal{M}$, the evolution of this prominent peak forms a ridge on the surface (the green line in the image below). At some critical point $x_\mathrm{min} \leq x^* \leq x_\mathrm{max}$ (roughly in the green dotted circle), the peak is no more and the ridge stops.

I think the continuous ridge (green line) can be tracked by setting an initial point on the ridge and computing the eigenvector of Hessian matrix. But I want to know:

How can I statistically tell the probability of the existence of ridge on given $x=x^*$ (e.g., $\sim100\%$ on $x_\mathrm{min}$ and  $\sim0\%$ on $x_\mathrm{max}$)?

My first idea was to fit the surface to a parametric model (something like segmented regression). But I think nonparametric method would be better, if possible.
Thanks in advance!
(EDIT) Answer whuber and Tim's comments.

This begs the basic question of what you mean by "ridge" and how you define it mathematically.  Could you please let us know?  And how do you define "$x^*$"?  This is crucial for understanding what your hypothesis asserts.  And how is this surface measured or estimated?  If, for instance, it's a mathematical construct, then hypothesis testing would seem to have no application: it requires some kind of probability model.  What model do you have in mind?

Adding to what @whuber said: you need to decide whether your problem leads you to define a ridge as a distinct local maxima in $z(y)$, or just a local maxima in $z'(y)$, or some other criteria.

@Tim Ridges in topographic applications are usually not local extrema.  Instead they are curves along which the Gaussian curvature is zero but the mean curvature (with an upward pointing normal vector) is positive: in other words, the surface locally looks like a part of a cylinder and is not a valley.  But in the literature of topographic analysis of digital elevation models I recall finding a couple dozen different (and not all equivalent) ways to identify ridge-like portions of a land surface model, which is one reason we need more information about the present application.

@whuber TimWescott Thank you for comments! I updated the post.


The "ridge" of my interest is the continuous evolution of the prominent peak in $yz$-parallel plane.


In my original post, $x^*$ was any $x$ value. I want to find the critical $x$ coordinate where the "ridge" terminates.


The surface is estimated from a family of curves, which are experimentally measured.


(edit: format)

@TimWescott In my problem, the ridge is a distinct local maxima (i.e. $z'(y) = 0 \land z''(y) < 0$). Other small ridges may exist, but I am only interested in the most "prominent" one.

I believe you should add the fact that these are measured results from some physical object or set of physical objects.  In my opinion the meta-answer to your question is that there is no best answer.  36 years in engineering tells me that if you put half a dozen smart people in a room trying to come up with the best approach, the probability of getting full commitment by all of them to one answer is close to 0%.  If you can get consensus that a given approach is probably good enough then that's usually considered a home run.

Thanks. Guess I'll have to pull it off somehow...
